# How do I disable rails form_with update functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form to add somebody to a waiting list.

```
<%= form_with(model: waitinglist, url: '/join', local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This works fine and it will post and add somebody to the waiting list. However when the page reloads the form goes into some sort of automatic resource mode that where the submit button magically changes to update and then the form submit magically changes to the HTTP Patch method.

I'm trying to understand what is doing this and I can't find anything in the docs.

How do I create a regular form that just posts to an end point but still validates the model? (and removes this update functionality).

edit added controller

```
class WaitinglistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_waitinglist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /waitinglists/new
  def new
    @waitinglist = Waitinglist.new
  end

  # POST /waitinglists
  # POST /waitinglists.json
  def create
    @waitinglist = Waitinglist.new(waitinglist_params)

    if @waitinglist.save
      flash[:notice] = "You have been added to the waiting list"
      render :new
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_waitinglist
    @waitinglist = Waitinglist.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def waitinglist_params
    params.require(:waitinglist).permit(:email)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is in `waitinglist` variable?

Comment: `form_with model: waitinglist, url: '/join', local: true, method: :post`

Comment: why are you giving model and url in same form_with, add only url there.

Comment: By default form_with looks for a resource route which I am not using since you can only add to the waiting list so I have to specify a route to tell it to point at the post route I created for it.

Comment: I've got a model there so that I can use the models validation properties

Comment: waitinglist is my model

Comment: Can you post the code for your WaitingListsController's create method?

Comment: @Jamesla did you try this `form_with model: waitinglist, url: '/join', local: true, method: :post` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are keeping a copy of your persisted waitinglist variable around between page loads. When your new page is rendered for the second time, since the waiting list has already been persisted, it is doing all the magical default Rails behaviours, which include updating labels for the submit button (create vs update), and the form's method (post vs patch).

You will want to create a new waitinglist if you are going to re-render the new page:

```
  def create
    @waitinglist = Waitinglist.new(waitinglist_params)

    if @waitinglist.save
      @waitinglist = Waitinglist.new # 
      flash[:notice] = "You have been added to the waiting list"
      render :new
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: ah makes sense just added <% w = Waitinglist.new %>
to the top of the form and all fixed. Thanks

Comment: It might be better to make a `@waitinglist = Waitinglist.new` in your 'controllers new method and `@waitinglist = Waitinglist.create(params)` in you create method. If you are using `render :new` in the create method if it fails, this will make sure your form will still have the values the user typed in on the first try. If you always use Waitinglist.new, the form will always be cleared.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by that, I've added my controller to the example above.

Comment: If you submit the form with invalid values, the model will fail to save and the page will be re-rendered. If you always make a new waitinglist (that isn't using the waitinglist_params), it will never have the errors presented etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think what u should do is if the waiting list is saved, redirect to new instead of render new. When u redirect to action it will call the action so a new object will be created. When u do render it render the view and I will have your persisted object, that’s why it is trying to update.